# Change classpath in Gradle caused ProcessException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-6.0-marshmallow

I changed the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'`
to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'` suggested by an answer here. The original problem was that when I updated from API 21 to 23, the `org.apache.http` was not supported anymore and I wanted to figure out a way and that answer had suggested to use legacy and change the classpath in main build.gradle as I mentioned above. This did not solve my problem. And when I changed it back to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'` my project cannot be built any more.

I get the following error:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':***:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I searched and did not find any similar issue. I tried restarting, cleaning project, etc. No success. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

you should use this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

> http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: can u tell me why changing it back to 1.1.1 causes the exception?

Comment: @Tina Did you try my answer .I hope it will help you .

Comment: did not solve the problem. I get this error now: Error:Android Gradle Build Target: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Tina set `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'` and upgrade Support repository

Comment: @amiya: yes I did try it instantly. The latency for answer was because I was waiting for gradle to download stuff.

Comment: buildToolsVersion is already 23.0.1   . support repository is being downloaded and it takes a while. I will inform you of the result. But what still bugs me is that one hour ago with gradle 1.1.1 everything was working fine. Why doesn't it work now?!

Comment: @Tina I guess when you use 23 its conflict with `1.1.1`

Comment: @Tina I assume version `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'` properly compile with `build:gradle:1.3.1`

Comment: No. buildToolsVersion '23.0.1' DOES NOT properly compile with build:gradle:1.3.1.    This is my current setting and I get java.land.npe.         My dependencies: 

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
}                                      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

Comment: @Tina Try with `1.4.0-beta4`

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta2'

Comment: Should I change both build.gradle files and change 1.1.1 to 1.4.0-beta? or which one?

Comment: @Tina You can set this

Comment: @Tina omg !!! How its possible .Okay . Last try with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`

Comment: I ended up creating a whole new project and copying my files into the new project. There must be some setting file behind the scene that had been changed and does not change back. Thanks a lot for your helps.